# How to do partition with last day of the year i wanted?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

So i've wanted to make a partition with the last day of year that i wanted, so i've been making a partition looked like this

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (BUSINESS_DATE)  
    (PARTITION D20200326 VALUES LESS THAN (add_months(trunc(TO_DATE('30','yy'), 'yy'), 12) -1,'mm/dd/yyyy')     
        PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
        STORAGE ( BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
        TABLESPACE DWH LOGGING NOCOMPRESS
```

And it gave me an error of

```
 ORA-14019: partition bound element must be one of: string, datetime or interval literal, number, or MAXVALUE
 Script line 14, statement line 14, column 100
```

But my select is success

```
select sysdate, add_months(trunc(TO_DATE('30','yy'), 'yy'), 12) -1 as last_day_next_year from dual
go
```

So i tried something simpler to get the date from the last day of the month

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (BUSINESS_DATE)  
    (PARTITION D20210131  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY ('01/01/2020'),'DD/MM/YYYY')))
        PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
        STORAGE ( BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
        TABLESPACE BMDWH_TS LOGGING NOCOMPRESS )
GO
```

It still didn't work with the same error

Comment: Does it mean you want the year wise partition?

Comment: I wanted to make a partition with less than the last day of the year of 2030, 2040, 2050

Comment: the string after 'LESS THAN (' is not complete. Why do you have the 'mm/dd/yyyy' there?

Comment: to convert it to the date..? 
Because i tried with select and it gives me an ok. 
Maybe i can't do that in the partition?

Comment: Be carefull, it's `LESS THAN` and not `LESS OR EQUAL THAN`. If you want the partition to include Jan 31st, you'll need to have Feb 1st in the `LESS THAN` clause!

Comment: Okay so it's better to make the LESS THAN value in the start of the month right? 
because let's say  the value of less than 01 Feb will be 31 Jan or 30 Jan (last day of that month) ? 
Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the rows into partitions spanning 10 years, use range partitioning with an interval of 10 years:

```
create table t ( c1 date ) 
partition by range ( c1 ) 
interval ( interval '10' year ) ( 
  partition p0 values less than ( date'2020-01-01' )
);
```

The database will automatically create new partitions for you at ten-year offsets from the date in the first partition.

Comment: So there will be a new partition called 'p1' then the value will be less than (date'2030-01-01) automatically assigned because the interval is set to be 10 years? Am i right? I hope you understand my english because i'm not so good to speak in English

Comment: New partitions will have a system generated name (SYS_Pxxx). The upper bounds will all be 10 ten year increments from p0, so `date'2030-01-01'`, `date'2040-01-01'`, etc.